# SSO Login using OpenID Sign-out is not happing

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I'm using the below code snippet to log in with Microsoft Azure this code I wrote in StartupAuth.cs for signing user.

```cs
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ProtocolValidator = new CustomOpenIdConnectProtocolValidator(false),
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
       

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
            {
                return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }

    }
    );
app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

But while Sign-out I'm using the below code but it's not working what am I missing?

```cs
var postLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost/PALMS-8.1/";
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri },
    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

while signout I'm unable to sign out not sure why due to Cros policy or what.

Answer (score 0):

The [logout process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-protocols-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request) in Open ID Connect is implemented by clearing the app cookies or removing the user's session. You need an active session to be redirected to post_logout_redirect_uri. Otherwise the logout will not work.

You can follow the sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect) which includes a full implementation and uses:

```
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

If you need to set the post_logout_redirect_uri to direct the user to a specific URL, it also needs to match one of the URLs that you have configured in your app registration.